# Python Conundrum: Guess The Song

Tags: knowledge, rebus, computer-puzzle, history, literature

[Python Conundrum: The Series](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A85112%20title%3A%22Python%20Conundrum%22)

---

The key to the puzzle:

[image]

The puzzle:

```
x = ???
y = ???

m = y + 1587

while m != y:
    for r in range(x, y):
        i = r * 2
        m = i - r
        print(m)
```

Hint 1:

> Take a closer look at cash from 2 countires.

Hint 2:

> The key contains 2 books and 2 banknotes. The banknotes come from the US and the UK.

Comment: It may or may not be relevant that the python code is rot13(vasvavgr ybbc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Prefix from the puzzle's creator:
xnor guessed the song's title. It is "Running in the 90s" by Max Coveri.*

Partial Answer:

> Phileas Fogg was the main character of *Around the World in 80 Days* by Jules Verne. Jane Austen is on the British 10 Pound note. Taking the number from the title of the book plus the denomination of the note gives us x = 80 + 10. x = 90.

> Ulysses S. Grant is on the $50 bill, and the book in question is *The Two Towers* by J.R.R. Tolkien. Taking the denomination of the note and multiplying it by the two in the title of the book gives us y = 50 * 2. y = 100.

> When these are input into the python program, the output is an infinitely repeating sequence of integers from 90 to 99. ie. 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 90, 91, 92, etc.

A couple of notes:

> I cannot figure out what if anything the 1587 has to do with the puzzle. This could have easily been a 1 and it would have achieved the same result.

> I am sure the body of the code probably has more to do with the title of the song than just displaying the 90s. For example, take r = 90 (the start of the loop). i = r * 2, so i = 180. m = i - r so m = 180 - 90 = 90. print(m). This could have been achieved by simply placing a print(r) in the body of the loop instead. I am not familiar enough with music to be able to figure out what to do from here.

Comment: You found $y$ to be $100$. So $m=100+1587=1687$.

Comment: @EtackSxchange - m has no significance, only script's output does.

Comment: From your code output, it seems like the song would be "Running in the 90s".